# True/False: Differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

If the differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is monotonically increasing, then $f'(x)\ge0$ for all $x$.

---

I feel like this is true by the Mean Value Theorem, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$$f'(x) = \lim_{y \to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x))}{y-x}$$
Now, if $y <x$ then $f(y) -f(x) \leq 0$ and $y-x < 0$.

If $y >x$ then $f(y) -f(x) \geq 0$ and $y-x > 0$.

Comment: So then $f'(x)$ will always be greater than or equal to 0.